# How to Create a mock column correlated on some other column with range

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I have sales column

```
date        sales   
2019-01-01  51.0
2019-01-01  72.0
2019-01-01  18.0
2019-01-01  162.0
2019-01-01  218.0
2019-01-01  66.0
```

I want to know how to create a discount column whose values will be in range of 0 to 25 and i want it 80 % correlated with sales columns. so if sales is more discount can go up 25 % highest.

output example

```
date        sales   discount
2019-01-01  51.0    3
2019-01-01  72.0    4
2019-01-01  18.0    1
2019-01-01  162.0   12
2019-01-01  218.0   25
2019-01-01  66.0    8
```

I am not able to figure out formula for mock discount. also it should have some noise.

Comment: Hey! It would be great if you can provide an example of the output that you are expecting.

Comment: @VidyaGanesh i have updated with example. thanks